# Bootstrap date picker showing empty box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I created a single page angularjs app, I tried to use a bootstrap datepicker but datepicker is showing small empty box instead of picker, If use the same code in a separate HTML page datepicker is showing up properly,(It's a year only datepicker, I have already tried many solutions but all the other ways also leading to the same problem. even jquery datepicker. Is anybody aware of this issue?

Note:
No error in the console,
I have included all the dependencies in index file,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution for my problem. The ordering of including javascript files was wrong on the index page. Now I changed the order and things are working now.

Comment: What order did you have, and what did you end up switching?

Comment: The order would be helpful

Comment: That's not an answer. If you ask a question here, it would be nice of you to include the solution when it is found.